# Apache 2.4 - restricting access to wp-login.php by IP not working

Tags: wordpress, apache

We're using Apache 2.4 as a proxy and I am trying to block access to the wp-login.php based on a list of IPs. Inside my VHost I have:

```
<Location />
  ProxyPass http://my_app_server/
  ProxyPassReverse http://my_app_server/
</Location>
<FilesMatch "wp-login\.php|xmlrpc\.php|admin-ajax\.php">
  Require all denied
  Require ip 123.456.789
  Require ip 567.890.123
</FilesMatch>
```

For some treason it still lets everyone through.

Any ideas on where my stupidity is affecting this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI: I have reloaded the server config already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think it should be like this:

```
<FilesMatch "^(wp-login\.php)|(xmlrpc\.php)|(admin-ajax\.php)$">
```

Or even

```
<FilesMatch "^(wp-login)|(xmlrpc)|(admin-ajax)\.php$">
```

However, this will not work with ProxyPass. ProxyPass takes precedence so the FileMatch bit is ignored. So this would need to be done in the app server, instead of in Apache. You can prove this by temporarily removing your ProxyPass directives and you'll see it is blocked.

It could be done using ModSecurity, but that's probably a bit overkill to install just for this (though a WAF is a good thing to have to protect applications servers!).

Can't think of any other way around this.

Comment: Hmmm... no go I'm afraid. Still allows everything through. It's like its totally ignoring the match.

Comment: Missed the ProxyPass piece. Have updated my answer. You can't do this with Apache config without installing something like ModSecurity,

Comment: Thanks Bazza. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have the following configuration behind a Apache ProxyReverse server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin tecnologia@unomedios.com.ar
    ServerName  myserver.net.ar
    ServerAlias www.myserver.net.ar *.myserver.net.ar

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://10.0.84.85:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.84.85:80/
</VirtualHost>
```

And in the LXC container

```
<FilesMatch "wp-login\.php|xmlrpc\.php|admin-ajax\.php">
        Require ip 10.0.0.0/8
        Require ip 192.168.0.0/8
        order deny,allow
        Deny from all 
</FilesMatch>
```

IP mask are really important: /8 match any machine on the range, and /24 match only an specific ip.

Hope this helps